# Does the Mets stadium apple rise for inside-the-park home runs?

Tags: baseball

Any time a Mets player hits a home run at Citi Field (or previously at Shea Stadium) the home run apple in center field rises. Does this happen for inside-the-park home runs as well?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this.  I can't find any video unfortunately that shows either way - there are only a few videos of Mets inside the park home runs at home, and none of them show the apple one way or the other, that I can find at least.

Comment: @Joe maybe that implies it doesn't rise....the SNY broadcast usually shows the apple rising

Comment: The problem is that inside the park home runs are often more involved than normal home runs, and don't involve watching the ball go out towards the Apple.  The most recent one that I could find involved an injured defender, also, and the one before that had a play at the plate and injured runner; so camera time for things more relevant to the game.

Comment: The ones I found: Tejada (2015), Reyes (2006), Anderson (2005).  All to right field, unfortunately, so no apple visible, and no shots one way or the other.